# Executing command with child_process.spawn returns no result

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm new using mozilla add-ons sdk, I want to execute bash commands from the add-on. [EXAMPLE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/system_child_process)

For example, I want to execute the command 'gedit' or 'libreoffice' (I'm using Ubuntu) but when I run the add-on, it does not work.

Add-on code (index.js):

```
var buttons = require('sdk/ui/button/action');
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

var button = buttons.ActionButton({
  id: "mozilla-link",
  label: "Visit Mozilla",
  icon: {
    "16": "./icon-16.png",
    "32": "./icon-32.png",
    "64": "./icon-64.png"
  },
  onClick: handleClick
});

function handleClick(state) {
  var child_process = require("sdk/system/child_process");
  var ls = child_process.spawn('/usr/bin/gedit');
  ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});
}
```

If I replace `var ls = child_process.spawn('/usr/bin/gedit');` for `var ls = child_process.spawn('/bin/ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);` it works perfectly, but I want to execute different commands, not 'ls', then...what's wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to execute arbitrary bash commands, you might consider using exec. `var exec = require('child_process').exec; /*eg, read a file*/ exec(cat file.txt);`.

Comment: @thomas  I think it's not supported with firefox add-ons SDK...